# UL/LI which flows down, then to the right when it runs out of room

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to create some HTML/CSS for footer navigation.

What I would like to have is main sections as separate ul's and then each sub-section as an li within.

The ul would have a fixed height, with the li's flowing down within. If they run out of room to go down, I'd like them to then start again on the right hand side.

I though this would be quite simple, and tried it with the following HTML/CSS

```
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="bold"> Home </li>
</ul>
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="bold"> Catalogue </li>
<li> Category 1 </li>
<li> Category 2 </li>
<li> Category 3 </li>
<li> Category 4 </li>
<li> Category 5 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="bold"> Company </li>
<li> Company 1 </li>
<li> Company 2 </li>
<li> Company 3 </li>
<li> Company 4 </li>
<li> Company 5 </li>
</ul>


.my_ul {
height: 130px;
float: left;
}
.my_ul li {
float: left;
clear: left;
list-style: none;
}
```

The above works, except that when it gets to the bottom of the ul it keeps going. Obviously overflow:hidden makes it disapear, but this isn't what I want. I want it to start a new column to the right.

Any ideas how I can improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do, you can't do with pure CSS, unfortunately.  You can with a combination of javascript and CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought this was probably the case, but was hoping for a pure CSS solution. I'll probably do it with some PHP to work out how many have been added, giving them a fixed height. The whole point of the text navigation is to accommodate those with lesser browsers lacking stuff like javascript.

Comment: Ah - yeah, PHP should be a homerun for that.  Cheers

Answer (score 4):

There is now a CSS only solution for this issue. CSS3's flex box model achieves the desired effect with CSS alone.

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Dr6E/

This will make `ul`'s content (the `li` tags) flow from top to bottom, and then left to right once it fills the `ul`'s height.

This is supported in most recent browsers Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and IE11 - as well as Safari and (with -webkit- prefix) and IE10 with (-ms- prefix).

Answer (score 3):

For columns you can use CSS3, though it won't work in older browsers nor IE9 RC.

```
#yourfooter
{
column-count: 3;
}
```

If your target group ain't likely to have any modern browser with CSS3 support, i would personally take the easy shortcut, by making a couple of div's holding the content.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know this will be easier in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way... CSS only, using the nth-child selector.  (This will probably have trouble on older browsers).

See the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MYB7g/3/

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;  /* space the two demos apart */
}

li {
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}


/******************************************/
/*  N = 2                                 */
/******************************************/

ul.rows2 {
    margin-left: 180px; /* li.width * (N-1) */
}

ul.rows2 li {
    margin-left: -180px; /* -(li.width * (N-1)) */
}

ul.rows2 li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,.5);
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;        /* li.height + vertical spacing */
    left: -195px;     /* -(li.width + horizontal spacing */

    margin-left: 0px;
}

/******************************************/
/*  N = 3                                 */
/******************************************/

ul.rows3 {
    margin-left: 360px; /* li.width * (N-1) */
}

ul.rows3 li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.rows3 li:nth-child(3n+1) { /* top */
    margin-left: -360px; /* -(li.width * (N-1)) */
}

ul.rows3 li:nth-child(3n+2) { /* second */
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;        /* li.height + vertical spacing */
    left: -195px;     /* -(li.width + horizontal spacing */
}

ul.rows3 li:nth-child(3n+3) { /* bottom */
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,.5);
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;       /* 2*(li.height + vertical spacing */
    left: -390px;     /* -2*(li.width + horizontal spacing */
}
```

Comment: I'll note that this solution uses a specific number of items per column.  If you still want it to flow vertically to fill an arbitrary height, and then wrap to the next column, I don't know how to do that.